# How to make divs position responsively depending on the number of elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How do I center these objects in a way that looks more natural and responsive to how many there are?

The layout is a single div with multiple divs for each gauge. I used .float-left to get them to go to the next row.

Could I get them to be positioned like this if there are 5:

```
****O****O****O****
******O*****O******
```

And like this if there are 4:

```
**O**O**O**O**
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

I believe to do this you will have to use either JavaScript or [CSS Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Flexbox is only supported in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) though.

Here is a simple example using flexbox:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLNR4/)

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrapper > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    border: solid 2px red;
}
```

---

Of course, to make this work in all modern browsers, your CSS will look more like:

```
.wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 1em;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-box-pack: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrapper > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    border: solid 2px red;
}
```